# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error An unknown FastCGI error occured

Tags: iis-7, php7

I am trying to make PHP 7.2.9 run with IIS7 on my Windows 7 Service Pack 1 OS and I keep getting the following error whenever I try to run `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`. I can see the IIS running with this URL : `http://localhost`. Saw a similar 7 years old post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176093/http-error-500-0-internal-server-error-an-unknown-fastcgi-error-occured) but it looks like they are using Plesk which is not related to me.

[image]

I followed this [Install and PHP Configure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php) (Zip File Installation) documentation and not able to troubleshoot what's wrong with my approach.

Do I need to enable some sort of permissions just like the thread I mentioned did? If yes, then how?

I was trying to paste my php.ini file content here but because of character limitations I am unable to put it here.

On some other threads, I noticed that some people had somewhat similar errors because of the VC++ version, so if that's the case, then I am using following on my machine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The download page explicitly states which VC++ runtime is required,

https://windows.php.net/download/

For PHP 7.2.x you need Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable, which is clearly missing on this machine. You need to mind the bitness, as the runtime you install must match the PHP bits you downloaded.

> Both [Jexus Manager](https://www.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html) and [PHP Manager for IIS](http://phpmanager.xyz) can warn you that in just a few minutes.